# On do statement

Tags: c

In the C specification 6.8.5.2 the do iteration statement is written alone, not
as do/while.

Why, maybe because are they, in that context, two separate statements?

Is this also explain the ; character put at the end of the while?

```
do 
{
   statement; // first statement 
}
while(expr); // null statement???
```

Comment: *In the C specification the do iteration statement is written alone, not as do/while.* Reference?

Comment: 6.8.5.2  The do statement The evaluation of the controlling expression takes place after each execution of the loop
body.

Comment: My copy describes this as `do statement while ( expression ) ;` (see 6.8.5). Also, The evaluation of the controlling expression (the `while(expr)`) does occur after the loop body.

Comment: There is no null statement anywhere in your example. The semicolon is a part of the do statement.

Comment: It seems your premise is wrong: 6.8.5 Iteration statements: `do statement while ( expression ) ;`

Comment: What's described as "The do statement" in 6.8.5.2 is just the name of the construct (though people commonly refer to it as the "do while statement"). It's syntax is show in 6.8.5, and the `while` is part of the syntax.

Comment: I second @nos. We have to distinguish between "the do statement" and the _statement_ in "do _statement_ while ( _expression_ ) ;", which in its entirety constitutes "the do statement", no italics. It sure can look confusing at first glance.

Comment: @n.m., if the semicolon is part of the do statement why then in the while is not necessary?

Comment: Because the standard says so. There's not necessarily any rationale behind the syntax. C is not a logical language.

Comment: @xdevel2000: All non-compound statements must be terminated with a `;`.  An explicit `;` isn't required by the `while` statement definition because it ends with the `statement` non-terminal, which will produce either a compound statement or a single statement terminated by `;`.  The `do` statement definition requires an explicit `;` at the end because it *doesn't* end with the `statement` non-terminal.

Comment: @JohnBode, what's statement non-terminal?

Comment: @xdevel2000: [This page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_and_nonterminal_symbols) explains it better than I can.  In the definition `while ( expression ) statement`, *expression* and *statement* are non-terminals; they're placeholders that describe what sort of text belongs in those parts of the statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In the C specification the do iteration statement is written alone, not as do/while.

This is not correct. C11 6.8.5 Iteration statements:

```
iteration-statement:
  while ( expression ) statement
  do statement while ( expression ) ;
  ...
```

> Why, maybe because are they, in that context, two separate statements?

No, do-while is one statement as specified by the syntax cited above. It is sometimes referred to as the *do statement* (as it is in 6.8.5.2), but the while on the end is mandatory, as it is part of the same statement.

> Is this also explain the ; character put at the end of the while?

No, the `;` is there because it is required by the syntax cited above.